# How do you reliably control sub process lifetime without having nested job objects?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

The [MSDN page on Job Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx) explains:

> A process can be associated with only one job. Jobs cannot be nested. The ability to nest jobs was added in Windows 8 Consumer Preview and Windows Server 8 Beta.

Unfortunately, it seems that this is just what I need. I'm dealing with a process tree like this:

```
server.exe
  |
  +--+ utility.exe
  |
  +--+ launcherA.exe
  |      |
  |      +--+ programA.exe
  |             |
  |             +--+ subProcessA.exe
  |
  +--+ launcherB.exe
         |
         +--+ programB.exe
```

I try to implement the following behaviour:

1. If `server.exe` gets terminated somehow (because it crashes, or because the user decides to terminate it using the task manager, or simply because it finishes executing), it takes down all processes beneath it. I use a job object for this.
2. If `launcherA.exe` or `launchedB.exe` terminate for some reason, they take down all processes beneath them. Unfortunately I cannot use job objects here since job objects don't nest.

As it is, I often manage to create 'dangling' processes by killing arbitrary processes in the above tree. I try to avoid leaving any stale processes behind, but all solutions I've come up with so far rely on some sort of watchdog process which monitors other processes - but if the watchdog itself gets killed, all hope is lost.

Comment: Keep the top-level job on server.exe, and make server.exe be the watchdog. That way, if the watchdog dies, the job object will take down all the subprocesses.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Sounds good. If I make `server.exe` watch `launcherA.exe`and `launchedB.exe`, I do notice when they get terminated for some reason. However - how can I figure out the child processes at that point? I'm using `WaitForSingleObject` to get notified about the process end, but at that time I cannot tell what the child processes are because they have already been reparented. I did consider `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` to keep track of child processes, or maybe WMI. Is there maybe an easier solution?

Comment: You said you had a solution with watchdog processes. Just reuse that solution (including the part that keeps track of the subprocesses), but make server.exe be the watchdog.

Comment: @RaymondChen: The issue is that my watchdogs always only manage to track one level of processes (direct descendants of themselves). If `server.exe` is the watchdog, I'd need to come up with a way to determine e.g. all processes beneath `launcherA.exe` *after* `launcherA.exe` terminated. Taking process snapshots probably introduces race conditions, so the only solutions I can think of right now is hooking the `NtCreateProcess` API or using WMI to get notified of process creations. I wonder whether there's something else.

Comment: Oh, I thought you had a solution to the watchdog problem already. Your job object will receive a `JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS` notification when a new subprocess is launched. No need to poll.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Ah, `JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS` indeed sounds interesting. Unfortunately, it won't tell me the parent process ID, so I cannot tell whether the newly launched process is beneath `launcherA.exe` or `launcherB.exe`. I guess I could take a process snapshot at this point to determine the parent ID. For what it's worth, I think you should put all this insight into an answer so that I can upvote and accept it. :-)

Comment: You can use `Process32First` to get the parent process ID. Feel free to write up your solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are misunderstanding what is the new feature [Nested Jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448388.aspx) which will be supported in Windows 8.

If you use start process `server.exe` which starts process `launcherA.exe` which start process `subProcessA.exe` and so on you need just start `server.exe` in a job. In the way all other children  (`launcherA.exe`, `subProcessA.exe` and so on) *will be started automatically* inside of the same job as his parent. So you can monitor all collection of the processes at once. You can even receive notification on every start of new process to create detailed log file for example. I did this on some applications and it works very good.

The only problem which you can receive is if some from the child exe are also "modern enough" and use Jobs to control *his* children. Only in the case you would have to use new Nested Jobs.

If I understood correct your question your current problem can be simple solved by placing `server.exe` only in a new job.

Comment: The issue is indeed what you describe in your third paragraph - `launcherA.exe` or `launcherB.exe` indeed support managing a job object by themselves.